# Networkx python calculating weights

Tags: python, networkx

So i have the following data:

```
  9 22 1 1082418256   
  5 21 1 1082434689  
  26 7 1 1082448725  
  27 28 1 1082457840  
  29 25 1 1082471683  
  30 31 1 1082485106  
  30 31 1 1082485111  
  30 31 1 1082485113  
  30 31 1 1082485116  
  32 33 1 1082485623  
  34 35 1 1082493130
```

First column is node_from, second is node_to, 3rd is weight (default is 1), and the last column is timestamp.

My question is how can i calculate weight based on number of links between 2 nodes. For example row

```
30 31 1 1082485116
```

should have weight 4 because there has been connection between these 2 nodes 4 times.

Thanks in advance!
 [This](http://konect.uni-koblenz.de/networks/opsahl-ucsocial) is the link to network with file below:

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you read [ask] and/or [mcve]? We would appreciate some code which shows what you already tried so far, all important information about the state you start from (how is your data stored? pandas dataframe? numpy array? list of lists? tuples, strings........?) and a proper formatting of data and code sections (it's just a matter of selecting and pressing Ctrl-k).

Comment: So the rest of th rows will just have weight = 1?

Comment: yes. it's just a sample from bigger file.

Comment: So it's an ascii text file, or what?

Comment: Great. in a moment!

Comment: It's opsahl-ucsocial format. Data is stored exactly as i pasted above. Columns are separated by blank space

Comment: Ok, then whatever _opsahl-ucsocial_ might be - it's column data in a space separated ascii text file.

Comment: Do e.g. `30 31...` appear always in this order or should a row starting with `31 30... ` considered to be added to the same weight?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's not specified in my assignment. I guess not because the link means sent mesage from node 1 to node 2 and it should be distinct. @SpghttCd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the graph incrementally and just keep adding the weights to the edge, e.g.:

```
In []
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
with open(<file>) as file:
    for line in file:
        e1, e2, weight, timestamp = line.strip().split()
        G.add_edge(e1, e2)
        G[e1][e2]['weight'] = G[e1][e2].get('weight', 0) + int(weight)

nx.to_dict_of_dicts(G)

Out[]:
{'9': {'22': {'weight': 1}},
 '22': {'9': {'weight': 1}},
 '5': {'21': {'weight': 1}},
 '21': {'5': {'weight': 1}},
 '26': {'7': {'weight': 1}},
 '7': {'26': {'weight': 1}},
 '27': {'28': {'weight': 1}},
 '28': {'27': {'weight': 1}},
 '29': {'25': {'weight': 1}},
 '25': {'29': {'weight': 1}},
 '30': {'31': {'weight': 4}},
 '31': {'30': {'weight': 4}},
 '32': {'33': {'weight': 1}},
 '33': {'32': {'weight': 1}},
 '34': {'35': {'weight': 1}},
 '35': {'34': {'weight': 1}}}
```

If you are willing to use additional libraries then you could create an edge list in `pandas` and convert to a graph:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['source', 'target', 'weight', 'timestamp']
with open(<file>) as file:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=' ', header=None, names=cols).drop('timestamp', axis=1)
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.groupby([df.source, df.target]).sum().reset_index(),  edge_attr=True)
```

Comment: it gives me an error in line: e1, e2, weight, timestamp = line.strip().split()

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3) .. i've added the link to network and files in first post, you can take a look if you want. thanks for answer!

Comment: it seems like there were 2 comments on the beginning of the fiile causing problems, it's reading the file fine now

Comment: kind sir could you share with me how did you get this output? it prints all in one row for me.

Comment: The above is the default for the `ipython` console. You can also look into the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint#module-pprint) module